# CSS based on element height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that changes its height based on the screen size because of the text line-breaking.

When the screen size is large enough, the button fits perfectly:

[image]

But when it gets smaller, the button stops being centered:

[image]

I tried applying `@media` settings:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer-content input[type="button"],
    #footer-content button {
        margin-top: -22px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #footer-content input[type="button"],
    #footer-content button {
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
}
```

And when the line break happens, it works perfectly:

[image]

But when it doesn't and the screen is smaller than 767px, it gets decentered again:

[image]
[image]

So I was hoping there was anyway of doing the CSS based on the button's height instead of the screen's width, but the research I've been making hasn't helped much, so, is there anyway of doing this via CSS or will I be forced to use javascript?

Comment: Flexbox will do this in its sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox. If this is actually an input type range you shouldn't even need to specify `align-items: center;` to get it to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/vo4xcrm5/

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.range {
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  max-width: 15%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="range" type="range" />
  <span class="button">
    Some type of button-like thing
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use display table and vertical align middle property so that the button and the range slider are always at the center of the container , something like the code below

```
      <div>
          <div style="display:table">
               <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle"><input type='range'></div>
               <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle"><input type="submit" value = 'something'/></div>   
          </div>
      </div>
```